# Is it possible to host my WebGl Unity Experience with Vuforia for an AR experience?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, augmented-reality, vuforia

How may I post my WebGL Unity x Vuforia AR experience on my FTP to make it work on mobile with Web ?

I tryed as if it was a "regular" (I mean not AR) Unity Experience, but not concluant (I even do not have access to the camera)

Comment: I'd say simply try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Vuforia with WebGL is not possible.
Have a look at the supported platforms [here](https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions).

Comment: Even though it isn't listed directly.. since it supports `OpenGL ES 3.x` which WebGL also uses (or at least an equivalent) it might work .. I would simply give it a shot and OP would know for sure ^^ Just because it isn't listed doesn't necessarily mean they even considered it as a target platform and excluded it on purpose ^^

Comment: It does not work. This question has been asked multiple times on Unity and Vuforia forums.